# Swift Firebase Completion Block Infinite Loop

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app that holds many books in firebase. I am getting a very strange problem wherein my application will infinite loop when adding a new book and keep adding the same book as fast as it can. If there would be any way that a more experienced person could take a look, I would be very grateful.

```
@IBAction func userHasBook(sender: AnyObject) { // Called after filling a new book form

    let email = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email!
    let school = email!.substringWithRange(Range(email!.characters.indexOf("@")!.advancedBy(1) ..< email!.characters.indexOf(".")!)) // for db organization


    //A few lines here that ensure that the fields are filled correctly (clutter so i didn't add them)


    ref.child(school).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.bookIndex = snapshot.value!["numSelling"] as! Int
        self.addSellingBook(); // we now know it is done finding the value, right?
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func addSellingBook(){
    let bookRef = self.ref.child(school).child("selling").child(Int(self.bookIndex).description)

    let book : [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["uid": (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!,
                "title": self.titleField.text!,
                "authors": self.authorsField.text!,
                "edition": self.editionField.text!,
                "price": self.priceField.text!,
                "isbn" : self.isbn] // this is the data that is added infinitely many times

    bookRef.updateChildValues(book, withCompletionBlock: { (NSError, FIRDatabaseReference) in //update the book in the db
        let newIndex = self.bookIndex + 1
        self.ref.child(self.school).child("numSelling").setValue(newIndex, withCompletionBlock: { (NSError, FIRDatabaseReference) in // after that update the index
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToMain", sender: nil) // and after that go back to main 
        })
    })
```

Thanks a ton and ask me if you need anything more!

EDIT: JSON BEFORE BELOW

```
   {
        "colorado" : {
            "numBuying" : 0,
            "numSelling" : 0,
        "users" : {
                "2nU0jp4ITjgQ6ElSQWc7t5qj62t1" : {
                    "email" : "vhegde@colorado.edu"
                }
            }
        },
        "creek" : {
            "numBuying" : 0,
            "numSelling" : 2,
            "selling" : [ {
            "authors" : "A. S. A. Harrison",
            "edition" : "Only Edition",
            "isbn" : "1101608064",
            "price" : "5.00",
            "title" : "The Silent Wife",
            "uid" : "eJvdVx3J8EYZPH3mlbYLBcPDkD12"
            }, {
            "authors" : "Jamie McGuire",
            "edition" : "Only Edition",
            "isbn" : "1476712050",
            "price" : "5.00",
            "title" : "Beautiful Disaster",
            "uid" : "eJvdVx3J8EYZPH3mlbYLBcPDkD12"
            } ],
        "users" : {
                "eJvdVx3J8EYZPH3mlbYLBcPDkD12" : {
                    "email" : "vhegde@creek.edu"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, I add another book (index of 2) and rather it keeps adding infinite books and infinitely increments index (numSelling). I don't want to post that JSON as it is like 300 lines long.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do with `bookRef.updateChildValues(.. ` are your trying to append your DB node with this book detail? Give your JSON tree.And is this where your infinite loop starts..?

Comment: It seems that if you have data in your database, you are retrieving it by calling `observeEventType` and when that completes it would run `addSellingBook`, and that makes it go in circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured it out, instead of using observeEventType, you have to use observeSingleEventOfType

Answer (score -1):

Please change Your code as i have implemented in below method to set online/offline.

// MARK: - User Online/Offline

```
func setUserOnlineOffline(userId: String!, isOnline: Bool!) {
        Let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FIRPATH_USER_USERID_DETAILS(userId))

        if isOnline == true {
            ref.updateChildValues(["last_seen": "Online"])
        } else {
            ref.updateChildValues(["last_seen": FIRServerValue.timestamp()])
        }

        ref.onDisconnectUpdateChildValues(["last_seen": FIRServerValue.timestamp()])
    }
```

//note: here you have to set string, so please replace dictionary of nsobject with string .. might be helpful to you

Comment: See. i am try to explain that how firebase function used. for above method, you have to write logic for that. i think you will get many objects in responce from Firebase that's why it will go in loop.

Comment: i think, you are just beginner in Firebase.

Comment: I am sure a firebase expert like yourself can elaborate on How would the solution to OP problem will go around. Please update your answer with actual solution not your suggestion. PS:- OP has nothing to do with wether user is online or offline...

Comment: I am teaching you how to write code and logic you have to developer. Firebase is clean pad, You have to set logic as per requirement bro. If you want direct readymade function then use XMPP.  here, we will show you path, but you have to walk on yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Altho i appreciate your *Teachings*. No one is asking you to write code. question was to how to exit an infinite loop. To which the solution is replacing `observeEventType` to `observeSingleEventOfType` because `observeSingleEventOfType` removes the listener from the network thread as soon as it retrieves it's first snapshot from DB while `observeEventType` keeps listening.This is a *Path*. What you are doing here is checking the user online/offline like in WhatsApp.Your answer is not even remotely related to what has been asked.I agree with you on ` show you path`, but show a related one..

Comment: Another solution would had been to listen to the node in `observeSingleEventOfType` retrieve the snapshot as `NSMutableDictionary` appended a `key-value` pair in the dictionary itself and set the value to the node. As `updateChildValues ` is generally meant for pre-Existing key-pair values in DB, not the one you wanna create from scratch but if you have a unique key, it will be appended a new key-pair value, like a GOOD HACK..https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data . :)Happy Coding

Comment: Or if you want to just update a particular child in a node use `runTransactionBlock:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122969/discussion-between-mehul-and-dravidian).